# Passing information using URL - UPS case study

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I am currently passing information through the URL in a SPD application I have built.  I have been following this tutorial (http://blogs.technet.com/b/brenclarke/archive/2009/04/14/creating-a-quiz-web-application-using-sharepoint-designer-part-2.aspx) but do not fully understand how I am passing information from one web part to another, or from one web page to another.  I understand it is a query string, but am looking for more information regarding other options.

For example, this morning I checked the tracking of a UPS package from the home screen of the UPS site.  I typed in the number on the home screen and was redirected to a different version of the same URL (I typed in the number on this page http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track and was redirected to the same with my relavent information shown).  If I were to build this process I would save the number as a parameter, insert it into the URL as a hyperlink, and pass it onto a unique page that would pull the data from other data locations (lists or databases) and observe it.  What is UPS doing here? I assume it isn't passing information through the URL since my redirect is the same as the original, but I could be wrong.  Please help with relevant links or information.  Thank you!

Comment: UPS would be using a POST request to pass the data in the body of the request rather than the URL. You can read about POST here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Perfect response (and timely).  How do I give you credit for the answer? I have upvoted already. thank you

Comment: I posted as a comment because I thought I was only addressing a small part of your question. I just posted it as an answer so you can mark it if you feel it's what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPS would be using a POST request to pass the data in the body of the request rather than the URL. You can read about POST here: http://w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp